# Hidden Markov Model to predict the next state

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I understood HMM so so but not training it very well. I could not figure out how I should setup training and testing in my case. I am going to explain my problem.

I am working on Foursquare check-in dataset to model a HMM to predict next venue category of a user (I assume it is the Forward algorithm).

First, I divided the area where these check-ins are reported into hexagonal grid. Let's say there are 200 hexagons. These hexagons are my hidden states. Then, I calculated transition probabilities for these hex cells by exploiting order of hex visits of users in time. The transition matrix is 200x200.

Second, I calculated emission probabilities by counting number of each category in every cell. There are 9 venue categories. Thus, emission matrix is 200x9.

Third, start probabilities are calculated by looking distribution of check-ins in each category.

Namely:

```
states = ('hex1', 'hex2', ..., 'hex200')

observations = ('category1', 'category2', ..., 'category9')
```

Till this point, everything is okay. However, I want to predict next category of a user if I know his/her previously located hexs and categories in a way.

I want to train my model, then test it and also show accuracy of my predictions according to the model. For this, the model should be trained with what kind of sequences? I cannot realize that how I predict the next category and more importantly, how can I setup the model to perform Expectation Maximization. Any effort to help me will be appreciated. If you want to explain these as code sample, you may write it in pseudo or MATLAB. Also, verbal explanation is okay.

Comment: Usually in HMM you have sequences of observed variables only (and not the hidden). If your data includes the grid location (what hexagon the user is at), then it sounds more like a Markov model, not a Hidden Markov model. You can still train HMM but the training is much simpler, because you know at each point the hidden state, so if I remember correctly, no EM is needed, only maximum likelihood estimation of categorical distribution, which you already calculated.

Comment: I want to clarify the situation. I have a set of check-in sequences s = r1r2...rt. So the problem is if we know category travel of a sequence c = c1c2...ct-1, is it possible to predict ct. For this reason, first I need to find hex travel of that sequence from category travel and hext. Then, I can predict ct by looking dominant category in this hex. This paper explained what I need to do in Section 3.2.1: http://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/~hcheng/paper/sdm2013.pdf However, I could not fully understand it and some help might be great.

Comment: For HMM classification problem, people run EM algorithm for each class and build HMM for each class but in my case, I could not figure out how can I split sequences in classes. I think I need to split sequences as training and testing data and then train only one HMM by using training set. Finally, I will be able to predict my test sequences from that HMM. Am I right?

Comment: Classification means predicting a single label to a whole sequence, thus you can train one  HMM for each possible label, and predict the label with the highest likelihood. But if I understand correctly, that's not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, it is not my objective. So what should I do? Namely, how can I train these sequences without following HMM classification steps? I think I need to use Baum Welch in a way but how?

Comment: Do you want to implement it yourself? Otherwise you can use Matlab's hmm training for discrete observed variables

Comment: I will use hmmtrain, yes. Merely still I could not figure out the setup of training. Let's say I have 50000 sequences and I divided them as training (40000) and testing (10000). How can I train my model now? Should I build transition and emission matrices by using training sequences and then perform Baum Welch for each test sequence to predict the next category? Or should I put all 40000 training sequences in Baum Welch and get a HMM model H' and use it for testing my sequences? Or any other method? My problem is this.

Comment: I can already build a HMM by training sequences. What is the point of using Baum-Welch in this step as it performed in this paper's Section 3.2.1:
http://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/~hcheng/paper/sdm2013.pdf